# Find the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Find the value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}$ ?

---

I know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}= 2^{n}$ and so, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}= 2^{n}-1$ but how to deal with $k$ ?

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172986/determine-s-frac222n-choose-1-frac233n-choose-2-frac/2173021#2173021  and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2171805/determine-s-frac12n-choose-0-frac13n-choose-1-cdots/2171846#2171846

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683733/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the binomial theorem, we have

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\tag 1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ reveals

$$n(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}kx^{k-1}\tag2$$

Setting $x=1$ in $(2)$ yields

$$n2^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k$$

And we are done!

---

Interestingly, I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159574/compute-sum-limits-k-0n-1kkm-binomnk-using-lagrange-interpo/2159760#2159760), that for $m<n$, we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k k^m=0$$

Comment: Nice Method !! Thanks :)

Comment: @JonGarrick You're quite welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 6):

There is also a combinatorial argument:

Suppose you have a room of $n$ people and want to select a committee of $k$ of them, where one member is the chairperson. There are $k\binom{n}{k}$ ways to do this. Your sum represents the total number of ways to select such a committee of any size (from $1$ to $n$) with a chairperson.

How else can we think of this? Instead, first pick the committee chairperson. There are $n$ ways to do this. Then, go to each of the remaining $n-1$ people and decide if they should be in the committee. There are $2^{n-1}$ ways to do this. Note that we can create any committee/chairperson team this way, as before. Hence your sum is equal to $n 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: My favourite kind of answer :)

Comment: Agreed, nothing beats a combinatorial proof.

Answer (score 5):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^nk{n\choose k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\choose k}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\\
&=n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{\ell!((n-1)-\ell)!}
\tag{by taking $\ell=k-1$}\\
&=n\sum_{\ell=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose\ell}\\
&=n2^{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Proof without derivatives:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n k\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} =\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!} \\
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n(n-1)!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^n n\binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
= n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}= n2^{n-1}$$

Alternate proof via probability theory:

Toss a fair coin $n$ times, find the expected no of heads. Let $N$ be the random variable denoting the number of heads.
Then $E[N] = n/2$ because $N$ is the sum of $n$ bernoulli random variables with probability $1/2$. But we also know that $N$ has a binomial distribution.
Hence
$$E[N] =\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}2^{-n} $$

Rearrange to get your answer.

Answer (score 2):

"And so $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk=2^{n-1}$". Nope: $2^n-1$.

**Sketch:** Notice that $$\sum_{k=1}^n k\binom nk x^{k-1}$$ is the derivative of $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k$.

Comment: Sorry, That was a type !! Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\mc{I} & \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n \choose k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{n - k}{n \choose n - k} =
n\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n}k{n \choose k} =
n\ 2^{n} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n \choose k}
\\[5mm] & = 2^{n}\,n - \mc{I} \implies
\bbx{\ds{\mc{I} \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k{n \choose k} = 2^{n - 1}\,n}}
\end{align}